# How does the OBEX protocol look like?

Tags: c++, bluetooth, obex

I'm trying to exchange data between a mobile phone and a computer using bluetooth. I'd like to use OBEX for it. I have read [OBEX_documentation](https://irda.org/standards/pubs/OBEX13.pdf) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange) and tried to send a following package from a device 1 (computer):

```
const char package[] = 
/* Connect | 2B of length| OBEX Ver 1.0| Flag| Max Size               */    
      0x80,    0x00, 0x07,         0x10, 0x00, 2048>>8, 2048&0xFF};
```

and I would expect some kind of respond from a device 2 (cell phone) like:

```
const char res[]={0xA0 .... } //0xA0 == Success
```

Even an error could would be great but I got blocked on recv(...).

It's implemented on Windows using winsock. I can pair and establish connection between these two.
Somehow I don't understand how to handle the data transfer. I have read the theory but it let me down.

This is how I send and receive:

```
if (send(s, package, sizeof(package), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
  auto error = WSAGetLastError();
  if (error != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) 
  {
    std::cout << "Unable to send packet ";
  }
}

auto receiveByteCount = recv(s, buff, 1024, 0); // blocking
```

Comment: Which service are you trying to connect? Not all services are OBEX based.

Comment: I know. I want to get a phonebook (vcard) and related things

Comment: Depending on cell it may have different services for such purpose. In common way you have to connect to PBAP. It requires additional parameters in Open Session command. Refer to PBAP Profile description.

Comment: where can I find a valid description? It seems like it's a secret knowladge...

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

Comment: thx :) I have already implemented sth like that:
   const char package[] = 
    {
      0x80, // connect
      0x1A>>8, // size 
      0x1A&0xFF, // size 
      0x10,  // ver
      0x00,  // flag
      2048>>8, // max size
      2048&0xFF, // max size
      
      0x46, // target opcode 
      0x13>>8, // target size
      0x13&0xFF, // target size       
      0x79, 0x61, 0x35, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xC5, 0x11, 0xD8, 0x09, 0x66, 0x08, 0x00, 0x20, 0x0C, 0x9A, 0x66 //Target
    };
But all I got is: \r\nERROR\n\r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229447/discussion-between-user-and-mike-petrichenko).

Comment: Back to my first question: which servuice do you connect to?

Comment: PSE - GUID{ (uint32_t)0x0000112F, 0x0000, 0x1000, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x5F, 0x9B, 0x34, 0xFB }

Comment: CRLF ERROR CRLF - is the DUN answer (modem). Show your connection code.

Comment: posted on the chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PBAP is describe [here](http://%20%20bluetooth.com/specifications/specs) (search for PBAP). The link was given by **@Mike Petrichenko**
The other helpfull post can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90a007e9-a385-4430-aba5-ba12a2a833da/winsock-bt-how-to-get-phonebook-using-socket-api).